# Start Index of a string in another string

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a string `"I'm stuck here please help, y? something else..... yyyy "`

I need to find the start index of `yyyy` i know the IndexOf method which will take a char.  If I use `y` it will give the index of this `y?`

Comment: IndexOf can take a string, which mean you can search for `yyyy` using indexOf. Why can't you??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also [.IndexOf(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) overload, so you can just use it:

```
var str = "I'm stuck here please help, y? something else..... yyyy ";
var i = str.IndexOf("yyyy");
```

Comment: its there the whole time tq

Comment: Hi, just a small thing do u know how can I get the last `y` index in `yyyy`?

Comment: There is also .LastIndexOf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Also if you know length of yyyy then you can calculate last y position

Answer (score 2):

`IndexOf()` method has an overload which accepts String input.

You can find some good examples here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof

```
string s = "I'm stuck here please help, y? something else..... yyyy ";
Console.WriteLine(s.IndexOf("yyyy")); // Output 51
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "I'm stuck here please help, y? something else..... yyyy ";
var index = str.IndexOf("yyyy");
```